# Best way to disable all submit buttons after postback

Tags: javascript, asp.net, jquery

I'm trying to write code that will disable submit button (or all submit buttons) on the page to avoid double postback.

I thought of generating my own postback javascript function (and inject postback javascript using `GetPostbackEventReference`) but maybe there are some better ways to do this? Or maybe there is some other way to avoid double postbacks?

**Update**:

I also want to figure out the best place to call javascript, e.g. if I call following script in the onclick button handler then button's server click event won't be wired up.

```
$('input[type=submit]').attr('disabled', 'disabled')
```

Comment: See my answer for another question if you don't want to fix this on a button-by-button basis: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28844217/787757

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://greatwebguy.com/programming/dom/prevent-double-submit-with-jquery/

This should help you

```
   1. $('form').submit(function(){  
   2.     $(':submit', this).click(function() {  
   3.         return false;  
   4.     });  
   5. });
```

Comment: I used answer from the link which was in the link you proposed :)  http://henrik.nyh.se/2008/07/jquery-double-submission

Answer (score 2):

jQuery:

`$('input[type=submit]').attr('disabled', 'disabled')`

Otherwise, iterate through all `document.getElementByTagName('input')`

May be best to do this only for child nodes of the form that was submitted, though?

Comment: That wouldn't stop a) `<button>` elements and b) the Enter key from being used to submit the form. That might not be a problem if you're only looking to prevent double clicks, but it's worth bearing in mind that this solution isn't a general solution

Comment: I also need some gentle way to run above code. If I execute it using OnClientClick then during postback button click sever event is not wired up.

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
$('input[type=button]').click(function() {
    $('input[type=button]').each(function() {
        $(this).attr('disabled', 'disabled')
    });
});
```

Anytime any button is clicked, every button on the form becomes disabled.