# Disable button after submit with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, django

I know there are a lot of questions about it, but I tried several solutions, and nothing works.

In my django app I have a form:

```
<form method='post'>
    <button type='submit'>Send</button>
</form>
```

I wan't to disable the button once the user has submitted the form. Using other questions, I tried several things, like:

```
<button type='submit' onclick="this.disabled=true">Send</button>
```

When I click, the button is disabled... but the form is not submitted. And for each try I had the same issue: either the button is disabled or the form is submitted. I can't find how to do both...

I'm using Chrome. Any idea on why I have this problem?  Thank you for your help.

Comment: Could you set the `<button>` to send the form as normal, then write a `script` after to disable the button once it has successfully submitted the form?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to disable submit button once it has been clicked?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3366828/how-to-disable-submit-button-once-it-has-been-clicked)

Answer (score 107, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('form').submit(function() {
  $(this).find("button[type='submit']").prop('disabled',true);
});
```

Comment: This keeps submit button values from being submitted. Usually not a problem, but it can be.

Comment: this is not disabling the button for me

Comment: @PrajnaHegde, maybe your button is an input? In which case, this is a more inclusive version: ```$(this).find('button[type="submit"],input[type="submit"]').prop('disabled', true);```

Comment: On some browsers (I've seen it in Safari) the button will stay disabled if the user presses the browser's Back button. So you need an [onpageshow to reenable it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12648785/4370999).

Comment: Any way to use this with submit button values and names being submitted too?

Answer (score 29):

I like this, don't have to traverse the DOM.
Put function on a setTimeout function, this allows make submit and after disable button, even if setTimeout is 0

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$("#btnSubmit").click(function () {
    setTimeout(function () { disableButton(); }, 0);
});

function disableButton() {
    $("#btnSubmit").prop('disabled', true);
}
});
```

Comment: it works for me because the accepted answer prevent the submit itself

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, for the reason @Jake pointed out

Answer (score 8):

You could disable it upon the parent form's `submit` event:

```
$("form").on("submit", function () {
    $(this).find(":submit").prop("disabled", true);
});
```

Be sure to run this code only after the `HTMLFormElement` has been loaded, or else nothing will be bound to it. To ensure that the binding takes place, fire this off from within a `document-ready` block:

```
// When the document is ready, call setup
$(document).ready(setup);

function setup () {
    $("form").on("submit", function () {
        $(this).find(":submit").prop("disabled", true);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Try, like this,

```
  <input type="submit" value="Send" onclick="javascript=this.disabled = true; form.submit();">
```

Comment: elegant and simple

Comment: nice but beware that it may interfere with your form validation

Comment: This is brilliant. Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

Something like this might work.

```
<button id="btnSubmit" type='submit'> Send </button>

<script>
     $("#btnSubmit").on("click", function(e){
          e.PreventDefault();
          $(this).closest("form")[0].submit();
          $(this).prop('disabled',true)
     });
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

This ended up being the best solution for me

```
$("form").submit(function disableSubmit() {
  $("input[type=submit]", this).prop("disabled", true);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

my variant, disable button, no direct disabled but only vidible hidden:

```
<input type="submit" name="namebutton" value="Nahrát obrázek"  onclick="this.style.visibility='hidden';" ondblclick="this.style.visibility='hidden';"/>
```

Comment: For me i tried this and worked fine, but it hides the confirm button only, where as i have confirm and cancel button on my page and i want both the buttons to be hidden

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this. It is work fine with me.

```
<form method='post' onSubmit='disableFunction()'>
// your code here
</form>
```

Then in script, add this

```
<script>
function disableFunction() {
    $('#btn_submit').prop('disabled', true);
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
onclick="this.style.visibility='hidden';"
```

I would say, instead of disabled, hide it.

If you want to go with `disabled`

```
onclick="this.style.disabled='true';"
```

Comment: For me i tried this and worked fine, but it hides the confirm button only, where as i have confirm and cancel button on my page and i want both the buttons to be hidden

onClick didn't work for me though.

Answer (score 1):

Got an issue on Chrome, wasn't submitting the form. Tried a bunch of different code, this was what worked best for me (and looks best imo):

```
  $('#form_id').submit(function() {
    $("input[type='submit']", this)
      .val("Please Wait...")
      .attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    return true;
  });
```

Replace **form_id** with the id of your form. Classes work too of course: `$('.form_class')`

Source: [JavaScript Coder](http://www.javascript-coder.com/jsform/jquery-disable-button-on-click-submit.phtml)

Answer (score 0):

I like this better:

```
<script>
    var submit = false;
    $('form').submit(function () {
        if (submit) { return false; }
        else { submit = true;}
    });
</script>
```

this way it also prevents the enter key to submit more than once

Comment: Nope, it is not submitting

Answer (score 0):

> I'm using Chrome. Any idea on why I have this problem?

Well, first time I dealt with this, I solved it like this:

```
function blockButtons() {
   $('button:submit').click(function(){
    $('button:submit').attr("disabled", true);
   });
}
```

This worked perfectly, but... in Mozilla Firefox. The Google Chrome did not submit it, so I changed it to this:

```
function blockButtons() {
   $('button:submit').click(function(){
      var form = $(this).parents('form:first');
    $('button:submit').attr("disabled", true);
    $('button:submit').css('opacity', 0.5);
    form.submit();
   });
}
```

This worked both in Mozilla Firefox, however, after that some of our users using old versions of IE experienced trouble of having two submits. That is, the one initiated by the javascript, and the one by browser ignoring the fact of onclick and just submitting anyway. This can be fixed by e.preventDefault, I guess.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want an element to be double-clicked, use .one()

```
<button id="submit" type="submit">Send</button>
<script>
$(function () {
$("#submit").one("click", function () {
//enter your submit code
 });
});
```

[.one()](http://api.jquery.com/one/)

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this. It is work fine with me.

```
$("button#submitted").click(function () {
        $("button#submitted").prop('disabled', true);
});
```

Double click on your button. This code will running

Answer (score 0):

You must prevent the form from being submitted more than once, disabling the button is not the right solution because the form could be submitted in other ways.

JavaScript:

```
$('form').submit(function(e) {
    // if the form is disabled don't allow submit
    if ($(this).hasClass('disabled')) {
        e.preventDefault();
        return;
    }
    $(this).addClass('disabled');
});
```

Once the form is correctly disabled, you can customize its appearance.

CSS:

```
form.disabled {
    pointer-events: none;
    opacity: 0.7;
}
```