# PHP avoid duplicates caused by long load

Tags: php

I have a site where you can submit data into the db. Everything works fine but sometimes when I click to submit it takes long time. I noticed that some people try to click submit a couple of times while it is still loading and this way they insert the same entry more times in the database.

What is the solution for this problem?

Comment: Post some code, more description,website URL ,  or we can't help you

Comment: You can disable the button after clicking with javascript

Comment: why would you need code?

Comment: No idea why this was downvoted; it's a perfectly reasonable question, even if somewhat open-ended.

Comment: @jantimon, good idea, you can post it as an answer

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to disable submit button once it has been clicked?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3366828/how-to-disable-submit-button-once-it-has-been-clicked)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can disable the button after the 
user submitted the form.

Here is a SO question/answer whith an example:
[Disable button after submit with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13606573/disable-button-after-submit-with-jquery)

If you don't use jQuery already you might use a vanilla js solution instead.

Comment: actually, I can't use this because I have a validation in place. So in case someone doesn't fill something, the submit button will become un-clickable for the second push.

Comment: I guess I will need to implement it within the validation script. So your answer is still valid...