# Issue when sending form with submit button disabled

Tags: php, jquery, html

I have here this form:

```
<form id="register-form" action="<?=$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>" method="post">
    <label>Name <span style='color: red'>*</span><br/>
        <input type='text' name='user_name'/>
    </label>
    <label>Email <span style='color: red'>*</span><br/>
        <input type='text' name='user_email'/>
    </label>
    //Another form elements
    <button name='register' type='submit'>Register</button>
</form>
```

To process the form, I use:

```
if(isset($_POST['register']))
{
    //Process
}
```

What I need is the `register` button to be disabled when the user clicks on it. I've found this solution:

```
$('#register-form').submit(function()
{
    $(this).find(":submit").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
});
```

With this jQuery code the button is disabled when I click on it, but PHP don't process the form. How to fix it?

Comment: It works for me [here](http://jsfiddle.net/8qe4mygq/), but I might have missed something.

Comment: Which version of jQuery are you using? You may want to use `.prop()` instead of `.attr()`

Comment: @JayBlanchard Even with `.prop()` the form isn't subimitted.

Comment: Could you see in console's network tab that `register` is not posted?

Comment: In network console all variables that need to be sent are empty and I have no PHP response.

Comment: Just moment - you want to disable button on submit?That action doesn't make sense, since page will be refreshed, right? Also, code works and variables are sent, btw (wrap code in $(document)ready(), just in case)...

Comment: @nevermind I want to prevent multiple form submitions. The code I'm using is inside `$(document).ready()`, but I don't get the response from PHP process.

Comment: I have just tested your code, and it works fine - but this is not way to prevent multiple form submissions - you can't save state of the button when the page is reloaded - if you don't do it with php... http://paste.ofcode.org/V83KXDHtt7sUqvvvA9uq6x complete code, tested on localhost

Comment: And your action attribute call same page, so, script should be executed on same page, which means - page will be reloaded. If you use ajax, on the other hand, and separate php script -> no reloading, and button state can be save.

Comment: @nevermind I do the form validation in PHP. No matter if the page is refreshed. I just do not want the user to take too many clicks at once.

Comment: Is your PHP in the same page? If so, disabling the button (as @nevermind pointed out) will not work as it will be enabled immediately upon page reload.

Comment: Then disable button with php: <button name='register' type='submit' <?php if(isset($_POST['register'])) echo 'disabled' ?>>Register</button>

Comment: @JayBlanchard Yes, the script runs in same page. May this be the problem?

Comment: @nevermind I don't want the button disabled after the submition when the page is refreshed. I need that disabled when the user clicks on it to send the form.

Comment: Yes, that is the problem, *the PHP must be separate*. You'll also have to re-enable the button when the AJAX returns.

Comment: You will need ajax and sessions then... After user submit form first time, don't disable button, send form data, create session var; after he tries it for a second time, if session var exists - disable button, and don't send data.... something like it...

Comment: @nevermind I've found a solution that allows me to disable the button and send the form. Please take a look in my answer here!

Comment: Please don't use unescaped PHP_SELF, rather use action="". Easier and safe (and a valid URI!). http://stackoverflow.com/a/25703224/4397981

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the solution by using a little hack.
How? I create a hidden input in the form called `register`.

```
<form id="register-form" action="<?=$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>" method="post">
<label>Name <span style='color: red'>*</span><br/>
    <input type='text' name='user_name'/>
</label>
<label>Email <span style='color: red'>*</span><br/>
    <input type='text' name='user_email'/>
</label>
//Another form elements
<input type='hidden' name='register'/>
<button id='register'>Register</button>
</form>
```

Now I send the form with jQuery:

```
$('#register').click(function()
{
    $('#register-form').submit();
    $(this).prop('disabled', true);
});
```

Using this trick the button thats submit the form are not disabled, only the button that call the function. Then PHP can process the form:

```
if(isset($_POST['register']))
{
    //Process
}
```

Comment: You have assigned a click event to an element you do not have in your page - `#register`

Comment: This seems way too complicated and doesn't degrade gracefully. Just add the form.submit() in your original code and disable the button... And even that shouldn't be necessary (check http://stackoverflow.com/a/13606633/4397981 ). I'll have a try at your code later to check my own sanity :)

Comment: I see the key comment there now "This keeps submit button values from being submitted. Usually not a problem, but it can be". I think the solution would be to submit - disable - prevent default (in that order!). Or; much like your solution, not using the submit button value as input (instead a hidden field or an variable in the action uri)

Comment: The submit - disable - prevent route didn't work - it gave rise to an infinite loop. Use the solution in your post, but don't rely on click(), instead let submit() trigger your code.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using jQuery version 1.6 or later you should use the [`.prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) method to modify properties:

```
$('#register-form').submit(function(){
    $(this).find(":submit").prop( "disabled", true );
});
```

Here is an [example](http://jsfiddle.net/360q932t/1/)

Comment: Even with `.prop()` the form is not processed.

Comment: See the updated answer @Dyan - I was still typing :-)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but even changing the `button` to `input` the PHP can't process the form. :/

Comment: Look, I'm using: `<input name='register' type='submit'/>` and `$('#register-form').submit(function()
 {
  $(this).find(":submit").prop('disabled',true);
 });` But still not works.

Comment: See the link to my example which is working. http://jsfiddle.net/360q932t/1/ Are you sure that jQuery has loaded in your page @Dyan?

Comment: Yes, the jQuery was loaded. If I remove the code `$('#register-form').submit(function(){
    $(this).find(":submit").prop( "disabled", true );
});` all works fine. I think the button is being disabled before sending the form.

Comment: Everything in the call would be asynchronous @Dyan, the button is not disabled until it is clicked and everything else within the submit function should run.

Comment: I pass the variables by using `$user_name = $_POST['user_name']; $user_email = $_POST['user_email'];` I verified here and the variables are sent, but PHP don't give response!

Comment: That is additional code you've not shown in your original question @Dyan, and actually a different question than your original. If the variables are sent and PHP does not respond it is a PHP problem. Edit your original post and add the relevant code.

Comment: Hmm. Try to remove the **id attribute** in your form and put that inside your button.

Comment: You can, and should, submit with the form's identification in the selector @aldrin27

Comment: Jay, I've found a way to perform what I need. Please take a look in my answer right here.

Comment: Having two items with the same name is a bad idea - it is like duplicating id's when you're not grouping something. Your selector `$('#register')` is not available - you have nothing with that id in your page, so that click event will not occur @Dyan

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this could work.

HTML:

```
 <form action="<?=$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>" method="post">
 <input name='register' type='submit' id="register-form" />Register
//I remove the **ID Attribute** from the form and put it in the button.
```

Jquery:

```
 $('#register-form').on('submit', function(){
   $(this).attr('disabled', true);
 });
```

Or as Jay Blanchard said if the version is 1.6

```
 $('#register-form').on('submit', function(){
   $(this).prop('disabled', true);
 });
```

Comment: With your code the form is sent and I get PHP response, but the button is not disabled... then I changed to `$('#register-form').click(function()
 {
  $(this).prop('disabled', true);
 });` and the button is disabled but I have no PHP response. God, this is making me lose my sanity.

Comment: I've found a solution to achieve what I need and posted as an answer here.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need this solution :

```
 <html> 
 <head> 
 <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7/jquery.js">   </script> 
  <script src="http://malsup.github.com/jquery.form.js"></script> 

  <script> 
    // wait for the DOM to be loaded 
    $(document).ready(function() { 
        // bind 'myForm' and provide a simple callback function 
        $('#register-form').ajaxForm(function() { 

            $('#register-form').find(":submit").prop( "disabled", true );

        }); 
    }); 
    </script> 
   </head> 

    <form id="register-form" action="<?=$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>" method="post">
   <label>Name <span style='color: red'>*</span><br/>
   <input type='text' name='user_name'/>
   </label>
   <label>Email <span style='color: red'>*</span><br/>
   <input type='text' name='user_email'/>
   </label>
   //Another form elements
   <input type='hidden' name='register'/>
   <button id='register'>Register</button>
  </form>
```

I got it from here http://malsup.com/jquery/form/

please try to change the action to target page,not the same page , then make any query to insert these post variables to make sure that they were posted correctlly

Answer (score 0):

In your form, put id in your button and class in your form.

```
<form class='Register-form' id="register-form" action="<?=$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>" method="post">
    <button id='Register' name='register' type='submit'>Register</button>
</form>
```

In your function

```
$('form.Register-form #Register').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#register-form').submit();
    $(this).prop('disabled', true);
});
```