# Getting UnsatisfiedServletRequestParameterException while trying to disable submit button using jquery

Tags: jquery, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I have single form with multiple submit buttons, each performs separate function like:

- Search
- Update
- Add
- Delete

All actions are POST, and use `name` attribute in button tag mapped to params in Controller side. Everything is working fine so far.
Now I need to disable the click of button while form is getting submitted and on the server side db updates are completed and server reply back.

So using `jquery` I added below code and then it stopped working.

**JS**

```
$('form').submit(function(e) {
   $(this).find("button[type='submit']").attr('disabled',true);
});
```

**HTML**

```
<form id="formSecurity"
    th:action="@{/security}" th:object="${securityDTO}" method="POST">
    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
        <div class="input-group">
            <input class="form-control" type="text" th:field="*{secId}" id="secId" placeholder="Find by SecId..." />
            <div class="input-group-append">
                <button class="btn btn-primary" name="search" type="submit">Search</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        ...
    </div>
    ...
</form>
```

**Controller**

```java
@PostMapping(value="/security", params={"search"})
    public String searchSecurity(final SecurityDTO securityDTO, final BindingResult result, Model model) {
    ...
}

@PostMapping(value="/security", params={"update"})
    public String searchSecurity(final SecurityDTO securityDTO, final BindingResult result, Model model) {
    ...
}

@PostMapping(value="/security", params={"addRow"})
    public String searchSecurity(final SecurityDTO securityDTO, final BindingResult result, Model model) {
    ...
}

@PostMapping(value="/security", params={"removeRow"})
    public String searchSecurity(final SecurityDTO securityDTO, final BindingResult result, Model model) {
    ...
}
```

But now looks like `name` params is not getting submitted. And I am getting below error:

```
WARN 16660 --- [nio-8989-exec-8] .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved [org.springframework.web.bind.UnsatisfiedServletRequestParameterException: Parameter conditions "search" OR "update" OR "addRow" OR "removeRow" not met for actual request parameters: secId={1234}]
```

Comment: When you use `params={"search"}` in your `PostMapping` configuration, `Spring` requires the url to contain `?search=mySearchTerm`. Your request does not contain the query string, so you get the error.

Comment: It's a POST request and params get resolved using the `name` attribute and is working fine if I comment the JS code.

Comment: You might wanna try this out first - https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-mvc-showcase. After deploying the war on your local, try this url - http://localhost:8080/spring-mvc-showcase/#messageconverters. I hope you are looking something similar.

Comment: @Dev The error clearly states that the request contains parameter `secId` instead of the known parameters `"search" OR "update" OR "addRow" OR "removeRow"`.

Comment: @Ajay, I can see the demo you shared is using RestController, but that's not the case with me.. Also I am using same request mapping, just that `params` is different. And `params` is assigned based on `name` in button.

Comment: @The Head Rush, I have updated Controller code for your reference. Yes, I can see  request is not sending this params, when I add the disable code of jquery.

Comment: I don't really work with either `Thymeleaf` or `jQuery` so i can't really help there. If  it seems like what you need to do is dynamically append the input value to the url assigned to `th:action`.

Comment: Try https://stackoverflow.com/a/36845948/9176702