# disabling a button not working inside the particular button click event

Tags: asp.net, button

```
protected void btnsave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    btnsave.Enabled = false;
    .
    . // processing code


    btnsave.Enabled = true;
}
```

But the button never gets disabled?
I just want to avoid multiple clicks (avoid data redundancy)?
(Even if there is an update panel, calling UpdatePanel.Update() makes no change)

Comment: This does not prevent the user from double clicks. http://tgynther.blogspot.de/2011/07/aspnet-prevent-button-double-click.html

Comment: To disable button, you can also use (sender as Button).Enabled = false;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it using below code:

```
OnClientClick="this.disabled='true';return true;"
```

Possible duplicates of

[How do I prevent users clicking a button twice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6137172/how-do-i-prevent-users-clicking-a-button-twice)

I hope it will help you. :)

Comment: where should this code be called? Inside the click event? or aspx page? Do this return true prevent remaining code from getting excecuted?

Comment: add this code in the aspx page in the button tag  and return true will make the further call to server side coding.